# jQuery. Select all elements with a class but without style="display:none;" attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following class, which selects what's inside of the td.lineitemtotal cells and uses it in the getTotal function to get a total of the cells. But, I don't want the function to use the lines that are in a tr.line_item_row with style="display:none;" attribute.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var line = $('.item');
  // so the line totals are calculated on page load
  getLineItemTotals(line);

  var line_totals = $('.lineitemtotal');
  getTotal(line_totals); // So the total is calculated on page load.
});

// get invoce grand total
function getTotal(lines) {
  var total = 0;
  $.each(lines, function(){
    total += parseFloat($(this).html());
  });
  $('#total-price').html('$' + total.toFixed(2));
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you want this ?

```
$('.lineitemtotal:visible');
```

This set contains the not hidden elements having class `lineitemtotal`.

Comment: Yes! took me 5 sec to qoogle,search,find :)
Definitely worth spending time writing this comment.

Answer (score 4):

```
var line_totals = $('.lineitemtotal:not([style*="display:none"])');
```

Comment: `+1` i was just about to answer that :)

Comment: What if element had other styles in it's attribute? Why not using `:visible` selector?

Comment: @undefined good point on your first sentence. I was assuming that'd be the only style. As far as not using `:visible`, I did that because visible also takes `visibility:hidden` into account, and the OP didn't ask for that.

Comment: Actually no, `:visible` and `:hidden` selects the elements based on display property. http://jsfiddle.net/8JPUf/

Comment: since style contains multiple attributes within, should it be like [style*="display:none"]?

Comment: @undefined I see. I stand corrected, then. I'm gonna keep this here as an alternative, though.

Comment: Interesting solution (`:visible` did not work because I first faded the entire div out, then ran this check before fading it back in), but I had to tweak one thing. jQuery (at least later versions; I can't speak to the latest version when this answer was written) sets the style with a space between the colon and the value, so you must do `:not([style*="display: none"])`.

Answer (score 2):

On your selector include the [:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector:

```
$('.lineitemtotal:visible');
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know for certain that the attribute will always be `style="display:none;"` you can use an attribute selector.

Instead of this:

```
var line = $('.item');
```

Try this:

```
var line = $('.item[style!="display:none;"]');
```

using `[attribute="value"]` looks for elements that have `attribute` with value `value`, adding the `!` before the `=` looks for things that do NOT match.